# Call Postgres function once at a time

Tags: postgresql

I've a PostgreSQL function where I want it to be called once at any point of time, i.e. no two or more calls running at the same time. Is there a lock on the function itself?

### Accepted Solution:

So what @calvin-furano suggested works but with some caveats:

- All possible advisory locks doesn't work with Stored Functions as it automatically runs inside a transaction. The lock will need to be unlocked before the function is ended (i.e. while inside the Transaction) which basically defeats it's purpose as it introduces race conditions.
- Stored Procedures works as it doesn't have this automatic Transaction wrapper. The down side is that the SP doesn't work inside a select statement, so for my use case I had to split the functionality between two steps; one locks and updates, another to select what have been updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS) for a session or transaction level mutex. The beginning of your function would try to obtain the lock. If the lock is obtained, the function would execute. Finally, the function would always release the lock once it is done executing.

For example

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION only_one()
AS $$
BEGIN
  SELECT pg_advisory_lock(1234);
  -- do work
  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(1234);
END;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Be careful to include error handling so that locks aren't held in case of an error.